# Load Dev Express data grid row values into textboxes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datagrid, devexpress

I am trying to load values from a datagrid I have set up using Dev Express, into text boxes when I click the respective cell.

I could do this using the normal `DataGrid` that comes with VS 2013:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        tbID.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString
        tbFirstName.Text = row.Cells("firstname").Value.ToString
        tbLastName.Text = row.Cells("lastname").Value.ToString
        tbAddress.Text = row.Cells("address").Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to do this exact same thing in Dev Express' `GridView`, I have found other topics that explain how to do it in `C#` but not `VB.net`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753) help-article - to obtain row cell value you can use the [ColumnView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowCellValuetopic) method as follows:

```
tbID.Text = GridView1.GetRowCellValue(2, "ID").ToString()
```

Comment: could you elaborate your code a bit more? I'm no pro at VB.Net... please show an example with the sub. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GridView.GetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic) method to get the value from cell. Also, you can use `GridView.FocusedRowObjectChanged` event to update your text boxes:

```
Private Sub gridView1_FocusedRowObjectChanged(sender As Object, e As FocusedRowObjectChangedEventArgs) Handles gridView1.FocusedRowObjectChanged

    Dim rowHandle = e.FocusedRowHandle

    tbID.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "id").ToString
    tbFirstName.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "firstname").ToString
    tbLastName.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "lastname").ToString
    tbAddress.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "address").ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: When i use the method you posted i get `Event FocusedRowObjectChanged cannot be found.` Don't forget i want to use Dev Express Xtra Grid and NOT the default datagrid.

Comment: @UriahsVictor What is the version of your DevExpress? You can try [ColumnView.FocusedRowChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowChangedtopic) event instead.

Comment: I have dev express 13.2 please let me know if i need to import anything prior to using your recently commented suggestion. I will try it in the morning

Comment: @UriahsVictor `ColumnView.FocusedRowObjectChanged` event was introduced in version 13.2. Carefully take a look at avaliable events of your `GridView` in Visual Studio designer.

Comment: could you please provide a snippet of the code with the sub rather than just pasting that one line? As i said i am not a VS pro so bare with me, i know how to do what i want on the normal datagrid that comes with VS i just need to know how to do it with Dev Express. Have you actually tried what what you are recommending? Please paste a snippet.

Comment: No im asking for an example snippet that you verified yourself as working with Dev Express. Just like i have in my original post where i pasted a snippet that verifies works with the default datagrid from VS. So im asking that you paste a snippet rather than just the single line, because your original answer gave me an "event cannot be found". So please verify that the answer you are giving works for the problem i am having. I am not a VS pro...(yet) so i find it hard when you just post 1 line of code rather than a snippet which i could read and understand. Thank You.

Comment: @UriahsVictor There are more than single line of code in my answer. And I tested my code before posting it here.

Comment: @UriahsVictor Have you tried `ColumnView.FocusedRowChanged` event: `Private Sub GridView1_FocusedRowChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FocusedRowChangedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.FocusedRowChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

This was rather easy to accomplish...all i did was attach a **DataSource** to my project then from the **DataSource** pane i dragged the DEV Express XTraGridview to the form, then i changed the type of DataSource in the pane to Details and dragged it over to the form and they are automatically in sync.

Adding a datasource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dd7z6t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396